# VS2012 doesn't break on exceptions for new project

Tags: exception, visual-studio-2012, breakpoints

I added a new console application project to my VS2012 solution.

When it encounters an exception, I get an error dialog, and VS2012 does not break and go to the source line that threw the exception.

The original project that was created together with the Solution does break on exceptions properly, so I think the issue is that the newly created executable is not marked as relevant for breaking on exceptions. (The debugger is "not attached"? I'm not sure if this is the right term)

How can I make VS2012 start breaking on exception in a project?

I am using the Debug configuration, the pdb is being generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an issue with recent x64 Windows systems when they do not propagate exception properly back to the x64 application when function calls cross kernel boundaries.
There are plenty of posts here on SO and all over the internet about it, for example [the-case-of-the-disappearing-onload-exception-user-mode-callback-exceptions-in-x64](http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2010/07/20/the-case-of-the-disappearing-onload-exception-user-mode-callback-exceptions-in-x64/)

You can fight it to some extent by going to Debug->Exceptions and flagging CLR exceptions Thrown column. But note that then VS would break even on the exceptions handled by you.